# Convert Object to String in java

Tags: string

What is the best way to convert an object I get from a database to String in Java? For example, I have a field which returns a BigDecimal. How do I convert it to String, while keeping it as null (primitive), if it comes back null? I was using String.valueOf(obj), but this actually transforms it to the String representation "null".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've noticed you get the string `"null"` instead of an actual null value. [This is by design](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)):

> **Returns:**
>   if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, the value of obj.toString() is returned.

That said, you could just check if it's null before converting it:

```java
import java.math.BigDecimal;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        BigDecimal foo = new BigDecimal(1.0);
        BigDecimal bar = null;

        // if the value isn't NULL, use String.valueOf, else use NULL
        String fooString = foo != null ? String.valueOf(foo) : null;
        String barString = bar != null ? String.valueOf(bar) : null;

        System.out.println(fooString == null ? "REALNULL" : "\"" + fooString + "\"");
        System.out.println(barString == null ? "REALNULL" : "\"" + barString + "\"");
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
"1"
REALNULL
```

[**DEMO**](https://ideone.com/qvzkm6)

Comment: thanks, I did just this. It just seemed a bit too long to write at first, but ok

Comment: @TiberiuDorianMoşescu You're welcome. If it's annoying to keep writing it, simply make your own util class and use `StringUtils.valueOfNull(foo)`.

Answer (score 0):

this is something you can do for converting those values into string values.

```
decimal dValue = 59.24;
String sValue = dValue+"";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think casting the Object to a String or indeed using `String.valueOf(obj)` would work, but just do a check if the value isn't null, like:

```
if(obj == null) {
   //Do something
}
else {
   String s = (String) obj;
}
```

Comment: casting will throw a classCastException or sth similar